# Is there a log for sshd where I can see who has used ssh to access my PC?

Tags: ssh, sshd

I am running the OpenSSH daemon (sshd) on CrunchBang Linux, and I want to see a history of who (i.e. IP address) has logged in using SSH.

Answer (score 2):

As CrunchBang is a debian variant, the openssh server logs would be in:

```
/var/log/auth.log
```

Answer (score 2):

Look in [`/var/log/auth.log`](http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?pid=357752#p357752) for lines of the form:

```
Jul  6 06:25:57 hostname sshd[10135]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=x.y.z  user=root
Jul  6 06:25:59 hotname sshd[10135]: Failed password for root from 50.30.34.7 port 5673 ssh2
```

(failed attempts) and:

```
Jul 12 12:12:43 hostname sshd[29412]: Accepted publickey for username from 1.2.3.4 9 port 32986 ssh2
Jul 12 12:12:43 hostname sshd[29412]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user username by (uid=0)
```

(successful logins).

Answer (score 1):

`sshd` logs are typically stored in `/var/log/auth.log`

`sshd` logs to the AUTHPRIV syslog facility by default.  As long as `rsyslog` is configured to send those messages to `/var/log/auth.log` you'll be in business.

Uncomment the following in `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf`

```
auth,authpriv.*                  /var/log/auth.log
```

Restart `rsyslog` for the changes to take effect

```
sudo service rsyslog restart
```

Login to the machine via SSH and check that the logs are being written